# Attempting to compare arrays and slice them with if else statements

Tags: javascript

Pig Latin assignment: The code is supposed to compare a vowels array with a word input by the user, then slice the word based upon the vowel location in the word. Currently works with some words, fails with some words. fails on: "dog".

My second JS project. I knew that I had to compare two arrays, so i attempted comparing them against each other in nested for loops, but I think that is causing problems. Uncertain as to why.

```
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const splitWord = word
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .split("");


  // Slice Word at first Vowel to end
  function firstPart(param1, param2) {
    for (let v = 0; v < vowels.length; v++) {
      for (let w = 0; w < splitWord.length; w++) {
        if (vowels[w] === splitWord[v]) {
          return `${splitWord.slice(v, splitWord.length).join("")}`;
        } else if (splitWord.length === 1) {
          return `${""}`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return firstPart(vowels, splitWord);
```

expected result is to have any word input be sliced at the first vowel and keep the rest of the array for the full length of that word.

so... "complex" becomes "omplex".

complex works in the above code, but:

"dog" returns undefined" rather than "og"

Comment: you are not using parameters anywhere btw

Comment: i had thought that in the ```return firstPart(vowels, splitWord);``` I was passing those arguments into the parameters.  is that not true?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your goal, but maybe using a regular expression could help here: `word.match(/[aeiou].*/)[0]`

Comment: @kiro check my answer, it should be fine for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will find minimal index of some vowel and `slice` from it

```js
const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
const word = "complex".toLowerCase().trim();

let minIndex = splitWord.length - 1;
for(let vowel of vowels) {
  let position = word.indexOf(vowel);
  if(position != -1 && position < minIndex) minIndex = position;
}
let result = word.slice(minIndex);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using regular expressions: 
I tested using your two words:

```
fromVowel('complex');
fromVowel('dog');

function fromVowel(word1) {
  var regex = /[aeiou]/g;
  var found = word1.search(regex);

  console.log('Index of the first vowel', found);
  console.log(word1.substr(found, word1.length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, First `trim()` the string and loop on string to check first occurrence of vowel, If found then break the loop and stroe the index of first occurrence. Then take a peace of string from that index to the end of string by `substr()`

```js
const vowels = {
    a: "a",
    e: "e",
    i: "i",
    o: "o",
    u: "u"
  };

function getVowels(str) {
    let string = str.trim();
    let index = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < 
  string.length; i += 1) {
        const st = string[i];
     if (vowels[st.toLowerCase()]) {
        index = i;
        break
    }
 }
string = str.substr(index, 
str.length);
return string;
}

console.log(getVowels('dog'));
console.log(getVowels('dOg'));
console.log(getVowels('vpnserver'));
console.log(getVowels('vpnsErver'));
```